# Simple commands to label equations by different types of symbols

Tags: math-mode, equations

I wanted to use symbols for certain equations instead of continuous numbering them. I first used following kind of labeling.

```
a+b=c \tag{*}
```

Then for other equation, I used

```
d+e=f \tag{\dagger}
```

This produced an error (even with inclusion of package \amssymb). For it, I used

```
d+e=f \tag{\dag}
```

This worked. But I want to put different symbols than these two and not numbers, since I have further equations. There are some question of this kind for numbering equations by symbols, but I saw that the commands are not so easier as above for (*) or (\dag).

Are there some simple commands to label equation by symbols?

(If the tags below in posting this question are incorrect, one may suggest appropriate and even edit freely).

Comment: You can use any of the following in the argument of `\tag`: `\textasteriskcentered`, `\textdagger`, `\textdaggerdbl`, `\textsection`, `\textparagraph`, `\textbardbl`, or combinations thereof (_e.g._, `\textdagger\textdagger`).

Comment: \renewcommand{\theequation}{\Roman{equation}} ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I input a comma separated list of symbols, the number of which must exceed the total number of equations expected.  I read this list with `listofitems` and then loop through the list to assign `\symboli` to the first symbol, `\symbolii` to the second, etc.  Finally, I renew `\theequation` to call upon `\csname symbol\romannumeral\value{equation}\endcsname` .

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
% HERE IS YOUR LIST OF SYMBOLS, MUST EXCEED THE NUMBER OF EQUATIONS TO BE USED
\readlist*\mysymbs{*, @, \textasteriskcentered, \textdagger, \textdaggerdbl, 
  \textsection, \textparagraph, \textbardbl}
  %
\def\symroot{\expandafter\def\csname symbol\romannumeral\icnt\endcsname}
\foreachitem\i\in\mysymbs{\expandafter\symroot\expandafter{\i}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\csname symbol\romannumeral\value{equation}\endcsname}
\begin{document}
\def\aneqn{\begin{equation}y=x^{\arabic{equation}}\label{eq:\arabic{equation}}\end{equation}}
\aneqn\aneqn\aneqn\aneqn\aneqn\aneqn\aneqn\aneqn

In eq.\ref{eq:6}, the power 6 is evident.
\end{document}
```

[image]